# Canadian/Iranian Citizen Transiting USA aiport

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, transit-visas, canadian-citizens, iranian-citizens

Do I need a visa or a visa waiver ? I am transiting through USA to visit Mexico. If I have a Canadian passport, but I'm also a dual citizen of Iran, do I need a visa just for the transit ?

Also, I am living and working in UK with a professional work visa. So my trip will start from UK, and transit from USA and into Mexico.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I presume you will be traveling on your Canadian passport.

You do not need a visa.  There have been recent changes to the visa waiver program affecting, among others, people who hold Iranian citizenship, but Canadians do not travel under the visa waiver program. A Canadian citizen's visa-free travel to the United States is governed by different provisions of the law.

See, for example, this list of visa waiver program countries, from which Canada is absent: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html

Comment: @MartinArgerami really? When entering by air? I am a US citizen and I've never entered by air without receiving a stamp. I would think Canadians would get them too.

Comment: @phoog Join Global Entry. No stamps!

Comment: @phoog: you are right. I checked my passport and my recollection is really bad. Only in Canada they do not stamp my passport, then.

Comment: @ZachLipton I only cross the border two or three times a year. Nine times out of ten I'm traveling with a non-US citizen, so it's not really worth it to me.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for your answer. Yes i will be using my Canadian Passport. There is another issue as well, even though my passport is quite recent (2013) it is not an e_ passport. do i need a e passport to transit through USA? Again, i am a dual Iranian / Canadian nationality with Canadian Passport.

Comment: @SaharTangestan no, you don't need an e-passport.  Your passport just needs to be valid.  See https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/619/~/visiting-the-u.s.---documents-required-for-canadian-citizens-%2F-residents-%2F.

Comment: @ZachLipton: I _like_ stamps—a record of where I've been.  I just wish border folks would order them chronologically instead of selecting any empty spot at random.  Was a major pain to organize the proof that I was not an overstay in Schengen.